# The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<User?>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<User?, AsyncSnapshot<User?>>):

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-streambuilder

In my streambuilder - first time i am getting snapshot null value. and shows me error.
Null check operator used in a null value.

Here is my main widget that shows me error.
Main app state:

```
 home: _getLandingPage(),
```

widget that shows me error

```
 Widget _getLandingPage() {
return StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    debugPrint('From landing method: ');
    debugPrint('User type: ${userType}');
    debugPrint('snaphsot has data : ${snapshot.hasData}');
    debugPrint(
        'snaphsot provider length : ${snapshot.data!.providerData.length}');
    
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data!.providerData.length == 1 &&
          snapshot.data!.emailVerified) {
        // logged in using email and password
        if (userType == null) {
          return const WelComeScreen();
        }
        return userType == 'TEACHER'
            ? TeacherMainScreen()
            : const StudentMainScreen();
      } 
      else {
        
        return const SignInScreen();
      }
    }
     else {
      debugPrint('snapshot has no data for'); 
      return const SignInScreen();
    }
    
  },
);
```

}

Debug Console:

```
From landing method:
User type: Teacher
snapshot has data: false
```

**snapshot has data: false**

After some time,  snapshot got the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
debugPrint('snaphsot provider length : ${snapshot.data!.providerData.length}');
```

throws the error.

If `snapshot.hasData` is false, when you use `snapshot.data!` will throw "Null check operator used in a null value".

You can use

```
debugPrint('snaphsot provider length : ${snapshot.data?.providerData.length}');
```

Comment: it also throw me Null check operator used in a null value" error.. althoough i deleted that print line

Comment: can you give me the complete error message?

Comment: I want to load some data before the page builid. that's why I called an database call future type that's will fetch some data from firestore database.  I called the await function on initstate .... after the data is properly fetched I called setstate to update the state.in the meantime I used a circular indicator. void initState() {
    isLoading = true;
    getData();

    super.initState();
  } `
  
  void getData() async {

    studentModel = await Database().studentAllData().whenComplete(() {

Comment: but the state builded before the data fetching properly completed. that's why it causes null issue. when i try to restart the code again, data fetched properly then no error shows... that's my problem... hope you understant

Comment: i need the complete code of that page

Comment: solve brother.. by the way, thanks